# Freemarker and java8 default methods?

Tags: java, struts2, java-8, freemarker

We've recently started to use java 8 default methods in interfaces, and looks like Freemarker can't see them:

`${myRatings.notEmpty()}`

```
The following has evaluated to null or missing:
==> myRatings.notEmpty
```

This is a pity because we're calling a bunch of methods in our templates.
Is there a solution to this? Maybe some patches?

Internets speak mostly of getFoo() default methods which indeed make not much sense, but I'm talking about regular method calls, not getters.

Comment: @biziclop did so but there's not much sample code

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update:** FreeMarker 2.3.26 has introduced a workaround for this. Quoted from the [version history](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/versions_2_3_26.html):

> [FREEMARKER-24](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FREEMARKER-24): Added workaround (not enabled by default) to expose Java 8 default
>   methods (and the bean properties they define) to templates, despite
>   that `java.beans.Introspector` (the official JavaBeans introspector)
>   ignores them, at least as of JRE 1.8.0_66. To enable this workaround,
>   either increase the value of the `incompatibleImprovements` constructor
>   argument of `DefaultObjectWrapper` or `BeansWrapper` used to 2.3.26,
>   or set its `treatDefaultMethodsAsBeanMembers` setting to `true`. Note that
>   if you leave the `object_wrapper` setting of the `Configuration` on its
>   default, it's enough to increase the `incompatibleImprovements` setting
>   of the `Configuration` to 2.3.26, as that's inherited by the default
>   `object_wrapper`.

Original answer:

How Freemarker sees objects is based on the JavaBeans specification, which is a cornerstone of many Java technologies. It introspects classes with `java.beans.Introspector` to ensure conformance. Apparently, JavaBeans doesn't support Java 8 default methods. `BeanInfo.getMethodDescriptors()` doesn't return the default methods, and we have the same problem with `BeanInfo.getPropertiesDescriptors()` with getters. I don't know why did the maintainers of the standard Java API (or of JavaBeans) decided like so... Certainly sooner or later Freemarker will have to do an extra round of introspection to work around these JavaBeans limitations.